# Change input box color and background as soon as some validation fails

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background color of an input box to pink and the border color to red as soon as some validation like required field, email address validation fails. I tried using :invalid in CSS and the required fields but none of them solves my problem. One of the fields in my form is as below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ext-comp-1004" class="inputLabel"><fmt:message key="registration.fisrtname"/>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="x-form-element" id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1004">
  <input type="text" class="required" name="firstName" id="ext-comp-1004" />
</div>
```

One of my validation message codes is as below:

```js
var reqMsg = "";
$('ajax')({
  type: "POST",
  url: "jsvariables.jsp",
  data: {
    "key": "requiredfieldmsg"
  },
  success: function(_0xef89xb) {
    if (_0xef89xb != null) {
      _0xef89xb = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/.exec(_0xef89xb)[1];
      reqMsg = _0xef89xb.trim();
    }
  }
});
```

Here the requiredfieldmsg is translated and displayed in specific language.

Can I add some Javascript code that does the above mentioned job for me (i.e. changing the color of border and background of text box) and can be added for all kinds of validations without hampering the existing code. Also, the box should becoming colored only after validation fail and not as soon page loads which was the case in most of the CSS tricks I tried. I am new to Javascript, so your help is most appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like all you need is [`classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) and some CSS like `.invalid { background-color: pink }` (because you're basically asking how to change the style of an element using JavaScript, right?)

Comment: So, how and where exactly would we apply classList.add in the above code, as we need that part post validation.

Comment: Inside the `success` function, I assume?

Comment: Tried it like `document.getElementById("ext-comp-1004").classList.add("mystyle");` in my JS file and added '.mystyle{
 background-color: pink;
}` in my CSS, but it does not work. It seems I am not doing it the right way.

Comment: That should work though: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/tzejorm8/ Use `console.log()` commands to do basic debugging, make sure code that you expect to run actually runs, make sure variables contain what you think they contain, etc.

Comment: When I use console.log(), it prints the message in console.log("hi") as soon as my JSP page loads since the script file is included at the top of the page. But I am unable to understand, how the JS part that I have mentioned in my post run. Ideally, it should print the **"hi"** msg at each validation failure as I have included this message inside the if(){} block in original script but it does not. If I comment this script part, no validation msgs are printed. Understanding this could help me figure out color part as well or if you can suggest some other solution, that would also be great.

Comment: You need to provide the full JS code you have. I was assuming the JS snippet in your question runs whenever the user presses a key or tries to submit the form

Comment: ...you have got to be kidding me. Anyway, I updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/tzejorm8/ to show the basic mechanism (validation = minimum length of 4 characters)

Comment: Is there any shortcut way to decrypt the JS code, instead of reading each variable index?

Comment: Even if there were, this is way out of bounds for this question. Also, asking on stackoverflow about heavily obfuscated code usually gets the question insta-locked.